# Both sides of a many to many relationship also relate to the same 3rd party

Tags: sql, many-to-many, relational-database

In a relational database. Two tables can be related in a many to many fashion with a mapping table that has foreign keys to the other two tables primary keys, while both still being related to another table.

For example.

> **Table A**
>   AId -PK
>   CId -FK
>
> **Table B**
>   BId -PK
>   CId -FK
>
> **Mapping Table m**
>   AId -FK
>   BId -FK
>   (composite PK of the above)
>
> **Table C**
>   CId -PK

How would I modify this so both the tables in the many to many relationship setup in such a way that a row from **Table A** and a row from **Table B** can only be related to each other through **mapping table m** if the row in *A* and *B* are also related to the same row in **Table C**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
1. Make TableA.CId and TableB.CId both FKs to Table C.ID.
2. Add a unique index in TableA on columns AId and CId.
3. Add a unique index in TableB on columns BId and CId.
4.  Add a CId column to TableM.
5.  Then Add two FKs in Table M,
   a. One using columns (AId, CId) pointing to Unique composite Index in Table A, and
   b. the other using columns (BId, CId) pointing to Unique composite Index in Table B.
```